# Woocommerce codeigniter Rest API

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, woocommerce

I am writing a API in Woocommerce.I want to get featured products , am using codeigniter framework, check the below code

```
public function get_products()
{
    $params = [
        'filter' => [
            'limit' => 10,
            'q' => 'Hoodie',
        ],
        'page' => 1,
        'featured' => 1,
    ];
    $results = $this->woo_client->products->get('', $params);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($results);
}
```

In this above code filter function is not working.Can u help me?